# getting an error System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00N000000FqP2cIAF; first error:

Tags: unit-test, custom-metadata

I am getting in MyTestClass

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 00N000000FqP2cIAF; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

I tried to access the id 00N000000FqP2cIAF but is in error, cannot access, might be deleted.

```
@isTest private static void testWhoCanCloseCasebeforeUpdate() {

        set<string> setfedids = new set<string>();
        List <Insurance_Claims_Case__mdt> cmsetting = [SELECT DeveloperName, Federation_ID__c FROM Insurance_Claims_Case__mdt];
        for (Insurance_Claims_Case__mdt icc: cmsetting){
            setfedids.add(icc.Federation_ID__c);
        }

       User triggerUser = [Select id, FederationIdentifier FROM User WHERE isActive = true AND FederationIdentifier = 'Icandothis' limit 1];

       Account acc = [Select Id from Account limit 1];
       Contact con = [Select Id from Contact limit 1];

       Case cs = new Case ();
            cs.RecordTypeId = Constants.RECORDTYPEID_CLAIM;
            cs.Subject = 'ClaimCase';
            cs.Status = 'Insurer’s Decision';
            cs.Origin = 'Phone'; 
            cs.Claim_Outcome_Reason__c = 'Difficultyt'; 
            cs.Payment_Amount__c = 2000; 
            cs.Sum_Insured__c = 20000; 
            cs.Premium_Refund_Value__c = 34000;
            cs.All_relevant_information_in_DataRooms__c ='Yes'; 
            cs.Date_referred_to_Client_Care_Services__c = date.today(); 
            cs.Trustee_Recommendation__c =  'Admit'; 
            cs.Trustee_Recommendation_Reason__c = 'Met terms and conditions'; 
            cs.Trustee_Next_Action__c = 'Prepare letter';
            cs.AccountId = acc.Id;
            cs.ContactId = con.Id;
            insert cs; 

        System.runas(triggerUser) {



            Test.startTest();
            cs.Status = 'Claim Decision';
            cs.Claim_Outcome__c = 'Successfully Closed'; 
            update cs;
            Test.stopTest();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Could you please share the entire stack trace and which line throws the error?

Comment: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 500N000000FqP2cIAF; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Comment: on  line update cs;

Answer (score 2):

`00N000000FqP2cIAF` has 17 characters, and is therefore not a valid ID. All ID values are either 15- or 18-characters in length. You have a typo somewhere. In addition, a 00N would be a CustomFieldDefinition, there wouldn't be any normal reason to use this ID except in very rare circumstances, and I don't see any reason why you'd need that ID in your unit test. You'll need to verify the correct ID to use for whatever field it is you're trying to populate (I suspect it's the RecordTypeId field, since that's the only constant, but I could be wrong). Try doing a search in your code base for that invalid ID, and you should be able to find it.

Comment: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 500N000000FqP2cIAF; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Comment: on line    update cs;  the error throws

Comment: @OneFourFour Then the problem is likely in a trigger somewhere. We don't have enough code to figure out what's up.

Comment: I check the ID from UI and it shows in the address line ..force.com/lightning/r/Case/500N000000FqPN4IAN/view                                                                        
here the messageLooks like there's a problem.

We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help. ..... If I will add the permission set how will I include on the test class

Comment: @OneFourFour Data created in unit tests do not persist. You won't be able to check it that way. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Maybe you do not have access to the account or contact record. Make sure that you are creating an account and contact in test class. Also check your setup rules so that the user TriggerUser has access to these record. Run as method enforces record sharing permissions. I would suggest creating a test user in the class so that you know what role and profile you are working with.